# Lodash: Constructing single object from many - Merging/overriding properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

> Note: I filed this question under lodash as I'm pretty sure it can help me solve that problem nicely, but haven't put my finger on it just now

I have an object describing different user roles and their permissions;

I will have something like 10-15 roles defined "like this" (*this doesn't reflect the application code but the problem itself*):

```
    var role1 = {
    views: {
        v1: {access: true},
        v2: {access: false},
        v#: {access: false}
    }
}

var role2 = {
    views: {
        v1: {access: false},
        v2: {access: true},
        v3: {access: true},
    }
}
```

The user connected will have multiple roles; In that example it could be `['role1', 'role2']`, and out of this I need to construct a single `permissions` object that will be a combination of all the props defined in all the user roles.

It is basically whitelist-based, where all "true" properties should override anything that was defined as false. Thus, the expected result should be:

```
permissions = {
    views: {
        v1: {access: true},
        v2: {access: true},
        v2: {access: true}
    }
}
```

---

I'm not too sure how to tackle that one without relying on crazy nested loops

Here's a starting point in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/usaQejOJ/1/edit?js,console

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Lodash has a few methods that will help to elegantly solve this problem.

First of all, the [`merge`](http://lodash.com/docs#merge) method. It takes multiple source objects, and recursively merges their properties together into a destination object. If two objects have the same property name, the latter value will override the former.

This is almost what we want; it'll merge your role objects together into a single object. What we don't want is that override behavior; we want `true` values to always override `false` ones. Luckily, you can pass in a custom merge function, and lodash's `merge` will use that to compute the merged value when two objects have the same key.

We'll write a custom function to logically `OR` your items together (instead of allowing later `false` values to override `true`s.), so that if either value is `true`, the resulting merged value will be `true`.

Because our objects are nested, we'll need to make sure our custom merge function only does this `OR` when it's comparing boolean values. When comparing objects, we want to do a normal merge of their properties (again using our custom function to do the merge). It looks something like this:

```
function do_merge(roles) {

  // Custom merge function ORs together non-object values, recursively
  // calls itself on Objects.
  var merger = function (a, b) {
    if (_.isObject(a)) {
      return _.merge({}, a, b, merger);
    } else {
      return a || b;
    }
  };

  // Allow roles to be passed to _.merge as an array of arbitrary length
  var args = _.flatten([{}, roles, merger]);
  return _.merge.apply(_, args);
}

do_merge([role1, role2, role3]);
```

Lodash helps out in one other way: You may notice from the docs that `_.merge` doesn't accept an array of objects to merge together; you have to pass them in as arguments. In our case, though, an array would be awfully convenient.

To get around this, we'll use JavaScript's [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method, which allows you to invoke a method by passing its arguments as an array, and Lodash's handy `flatten` method, which takes an array that might contain nested arrays — like `[1, [2, 3], [4, 5]]` — and flattens it into `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

So we'll gather up all the arguments we need in a `flatten`ed array, and then `apply` them to `merge`!

If your objects are nested very very deeply, there's a chance you'll overflow the stack calling `merger` recursively like this, but for your objects this should work just fine.

Comment: Wow I couldn't hope for an answer explained that well! Million thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this further using **_.assign,** **_.map,** and **_.pickBy** instead.

Shown below is an improved solution in just three lines.

```js
// example data
const roles = [
  {
    name: 'role1',
    views: {
      v1: { access: true },
      v2: { access: false },
      v3: { access: false },
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'role2',
    views: {
      v1: { access: false },
      v2: { access: true },
      v3: { access: true },
    },
  },
];

// merge logic
const _ = require('lodash');
const roleViews = _.map(roles, role => _.pickBy(role.views, v => v.access));
const views = _.assign({}, ...roleViews);
const permissions = { views };

console.log(permissions);
```