# Javascript object literal template: Extending implementation object with a baseline

Tags: javascript, jquery, software-design

I'm working with javascript object literals, and got the brilliant idea that I'd streamline the actual object literal I had to work with, by abstracting all the common attributes away.

As such I'd like to extend/inherit/merge my concrete object from a baseline predefined object structure. 
What I mean is something like this:

**Baseline:**

```
{  
       "id":"",
       "options":[  
          {  
             "1":true,
              "concreteValue":"important"
          },
          {  
             "2":false,
              "concreteValue":"unimportant"
          },
          {  
             "3":true,
             "concreteValue":"important"
          }
       ],
       "greeting":"Howdy",
       "player":{  
          "name":"",
          "hp":1,
          "mana":10
       }
}
```

**Concrete:**

```
{  
   "id":"player1",
   "options":[  
      {  
         "5":true,
          "concreteValue":"awesome"
      }
   ],
   "greeting":"Greetings!",
   "player":{  
      "name":"player1",
      "hp":15
   }
}
```

and through extending/inheriting/merging `concrete` with `baseline`, I want the output to be this:

```
{  
   "id":"player1",
   "options":[  
      {  
         "1":true,
         "concreteValue":"important"
      },
      {  
         "2":false,
         "concreteValue":"unimportant"
      },
      {  
         "3":true,
         "concreteValue":"important"
      },
      {  
         "5":true,
         "concreteValue":"awesome"
      }
   ],
   "greeting":"Greetings!",
   "player":{  
      "name":"player1",
      "hp":15,
      "mana":10
   }
}
```

So values that exist both places are overwritten by those in concrete, values that does not already exist are added. 
This seem like a good way of doing things, so I'm sure there's a smart way of doing this, that I haven't found yet :)
I looked at [jQuery Extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), but it doesn't seem to merge values by the same name into each other.

I tried using `concat` and `Object.Assign`, but they didn't do the trick either. 
Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: There is no built in solution in JavaScript for the behavior you want. To achieve the final merged object, you will need to iterate the keys in `concrete`.

Comment: By the way, this has absolutely nothing to do with JSON, which is nothing more than a serialization format. You are talking about JavaScript object literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lodash** library can be used here.

I would probably choose @DelightedD0D solution not to add additional library if that's the only thing you will use **Lodash** for.

The advantage of using **Lodash** would be the `customizer` function where you can specify some custom merge goodies although i don't know if that is possible in **jQuery** `extend` approach.

You can use `merge(src, dest, customizer)` function to get what you described, here is the result:
http://jsbin.com/qibeji/edit?js,console

**Lodash** and **Underscore** are most optimal libraries for advanced javascript object manipulation.

Take a look at this two questions for a detailed overview of what you can do:
[Lodash - difference between .extend() / .assign() and .merge()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965844/lodash-difference-between-extend-assign-and-merge)
[Lodash: Constructing single object from many - Merging/overriding properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120276/lodash-constructing-single-object-from-many-merging-overriding-properties)

Comment: This does not merge the objects correctly, see http://prnt.sc/akieg3. See how the values for 1 and 5 are  in the same object? and there are only 3 objects in the options object where there should now be 4. This is equivalent to `jQuery.extend()` by itself I dont think you can do this automatically with any lib without changing the structure of the JSON.

Comment: True, need some modification

Comment: Using an array inside the options object causes keys 0 of each object to be merged, they need to have named keys to prevent that

Comment: @DelightedD0D Updaited the answer, changed jsbin link

Comment: @yup That'll do it :)

Comment: Now that it works... the only advantage of this approach would be the `customizer` function.

Comment: I would've liked an unbiased function, but in my mind this is the most versatile solution to a generic problem - albeit it not a perfect one :)

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you could change the strcture of the `options` objects like below, then `jQuery.extend(true, baseline, concrete)` would work

```
"options": {
    "5": {
      "someName": true,
      "concreteValue": "important"
    }
  },
```

#### [See this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/7suowhqn/2/) which produces this result:

[image]

Comment: Creating nested objects instead of array entries does seem to work :)
But I'd still like to be able to use arrays. Having to think of unique names is so tedious ;)