# Compare the highest value between two different objects for each property and value

Tags: javascript

I have two objects

```
object1 = {num: 0, num2: 0}
object2 = {num: 3, num2: 0}
```

I would like to compare both objects and get the highest one per object key, so my end results should be

```
result = {num: 3, num2: 0}
```

or if I had

```
object1 = {num: 0, num2: 0}
object2 = {num: 100, num2: 15}
```

I should get

```
result = {num: 100, num2: 15}
```

The highest math value per key.

The goal is to go through each object key comparing the two objects and pulling the highest numbered one. Per key also "num" is a var it can be anything and there could be more than two for example "num", "num1", "num2", "num3" and so forth.

Comment: Sounds interesting. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? This sounds like a job for lodash with a custom merge (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120276/lodash-constructing-single-object-from-many-merging-overriding-properties).

Comment: Can you please clarify the _"value per key"_ part. `{num: 10, num2: 0}, {num: 0, num2: 10}` should return `{ num: 10, num2: 10}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic solution:

```
let ob1 = {a: 1, c:4};
let ob2 = {a: 2, b:3};
let ob3 = {b:5};

let lamba = function(...objects) {
    let result = {};
    objects.forEach(function (object) {
        for(let key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof object[key] === "number") {
                result[key] = result[key] || 0;
                result[key] = (object[key] > result[key]) ? object[key] : result[key];
            }
        }
    });
    return result
};

let result = lamba(ob1, ob2, ob3);

console.log(result); // { a: 2, c: 4, b: 5 }
```

Comment: If for example, b is NaN I get 0 any ideas why?

Comment: I expected all obj values to be "normal" numbers. NaN is a special case `typeof NaN === "number"` and `NaN > 0 === false` so if you have a NaN it will be more or less casted to 0, because it is a Number but it is smaller than every value. If you don't want that, you would have to treat it as special case `if (object[key] === NaN && typeof result[key] === "undefined") {/* do something special with NaN*/}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to firstly get the keys from one of your objects and then use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build a new object from those keys. For each newly created key in the object, you can get the max of all the values for that key from the passed-in objects. This can be achieved by mapping each value to an array with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then getting the maximum number from that array. This approach will work for *N* objects which all have the same keys.

See example below:

```js
const object1 = {num: 0, num2: 10, num3: 5};
const object2 = {num: 3, num2: 0, num3: 2};
const object3 = {num: 3, num2: NaN, num3: 2};

const getMaxObject = (...objects) => {
  const keys = objects.map(Object.keys).reduce((acc, arr) => acc.length > arr.length ? acc : arr, []);
  return keys.reduce(
    (acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]: Math.max(...objects.map(
      o => o[key] || 0
    ))}), {}
  );
}

console.log(getMaxObject(object1, object2, object3));
```

Comment: This works great, but if I have the following num2: NaN, or Null it ignores it how can I fix that?

Comment: @AlmogKoren Hi, I've updated my answer to use `.filter()` on the `.map()` results to filter out anything falsey, like `undefined`, `null`, etc.  Does that fix your issue?

Comment: I don't want to filter it out, just ignore the value if you filter out then my final results will be missing for example num2

Comment: @AlmogKoren I'm not sure I follow, above `num2` in the 3rd object is `NaN` and `num2` is present in the final object?

Comment: If I have the following objects, from the top the final results should be like so 
const object3 = {num: 3, num2: 10, num3: 5};

It just ignores the NaN and uses 10 as it's the highest

Comment: @AlmogKoren when I run the code snippet above on the three objects (with `num2` in the third being `NaN`) I get `{ "num": 3, "num2": 10, "num3": 5}` (which seems to be the result you're after), is that no what you get when you click "run code snippet"?

Comment: No, here is my real data 
First object {date_created: 1546293600000, num: 370}
Second object date_created: 1546380000000, num: 370, num2: NaN}
Results {date_created: 1546293600000, num: 370}

Due not that it's rows so, for example, I have at the start 
{date_created: "2019-01-01", num: 100, num2: 300, category: "A"}

Comment: So one row can be NaN and another row can be 10, if it's NaN or undefied it should be like it's 0, I don't want to filter out key

Comment: @AlmogKoren ok, I see what the issue is, just to clarify, what do you expect the result to be for the two objects  are `{date_created: 1546293600000, num: 370}` and `{date_created: 1546380000000, num: 370, num2: NaN}` ?

Comment: So for 
{date_created: 1546293600000, num: 370}
{date_created: 1546380000000, num: 370, num2: NaN}
{date_created: 1546380000000, num: 100, num2: 50}

I would like to get the following 
{num: 370, num2: 50}

Comment: @AlmogKoren okay, I've updated my answer. The issue before was that the function was taking the keys from the first object, not the object with the largest amount of keys, the function does this now. If the function encounters `NaN` (or another falsey value, it uses `0`). Does this work for you? See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yjveqt49/) for an example using the objects you mentioned in the comments

Comment: I just tested the there are two issues, I'm getting 
my first results are {date_created: NaN, num: 100, num2: 300, category: NaN}

Which should be just {num: 100, num2: 300}

Then I have an object were num2 is NaN and the results are 

{date_created: 1546293600000, num: 370, num2: 0}

Which should be {num: 370, num2: 300}

if the key vaule is NaN, undefined or just not a number it needs to ignore so when I get the max number it will always have the highest one

Comment: @AlmogKoren so you only want the keys which start with `num` ? Also can you give the objects where `num2` becomes `NaN`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204484/discussion-between-nick-parsons-and-almog-koren).

Answer (score -1):

[hope this helps](https://codepen.io/sumanth-bettadapura/pen/XWJNKyY?editors=0111)

```js
let high1 = 0, high2 = 0;
const object1 = {num: 0, num2: 0}
const object2 = {num: 3, num2: 0}

Object.keys(object1).forEach(item =>{
  if(object1[item] > high1){
    high2 = high1;
    high1 = object1[item]; 
  }
});

Object.keys(object2).forEach(item =>{
  if(object2[item] > high1){
    high2 = high1;
    high1 = object2[item]; 
  }
});

let result = {
  num : high1,
  num2 : high2,
}

console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you choose to keep your numbers object inside an array.

```html
let high1 = 0, high2 = 0;

const numbers = [
  {num: 0, num2: 0},
  {num: 3, num2: 0}
];

numbers.forEach( itemA =>{
  Object.keys(itemA).forEach(item =>{
    if(itemA[item] > high1){
      high2 = high1;
      high1 = itemA[item]; 
    }
  });
});

let result = {
  num : high1,
  num2 : high2,
}
```